# celery worker only imports tasks when not detached

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to get my django app to submit tasks to a celery worker and it's succeeding when the worker is run attached. As soon as I add the --detach the tasks are failing to be registered.

```
[2020-10-26 04:09:33,159: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'devapp.tasks.create_random_files'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
'[[20, "blah", 5120], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (93b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pysite/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 562, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'devapp.tasks.create_random_files'
```

In my tasks.py I have

```
import os
import string
import subprocess
from celery import shared_task, task

@shared_task(name='devapp.tasks.create_random_files')
def create_random_files(total,filename,size):
    for i in range(int(total)):
        filenum = str(i).zfill(5)
        rnd_filename = '/brdis/{}-{}'.format(filenum,filename)
        with open(rnd_filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(os.urandom(size))
            f.close
    return '{} random files created'.format(total)
```

and in my views.py I have

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.shortcuts import redirect

from .forms import CreateRandomFilesForm, GetFileListForm, ClamScanFileForm
from .tasks import create_random_files, clamscanfile

class ClamScanFileView(FormView):
    template_name = 'devapp/clamscan_file.html'
    form_class = ClamScanFileForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        filename = form.cleaned_data.get('filename')
        clamscanfile.delay(filename)
        messages.success(self.request, 'We are scanning your file!s Wait a moment and refresh this page.')
        return redirect('files_list')
```

I understand that it may be relative imports(something else i need to get my head round) but I don't understand why adding the --detach to the celery worker command produces this error:

`celery -A project worker -E --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/celeryd.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celeryd.pid`

works fine but...

`celery -A project worker -E --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/var/log/celery/celeryd.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celeryd.pid --detach`

starts the worker but doesn't register the tasks?

Any help appreciated.

FWIW

```
celery report

software -> celery:4.4.7 (cliffs) kombu:4.6.11 py:3.6.8
            billiard:3.6.3.0 py-amqp:2.6.1
platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit, ELF
            kernel version:3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64 imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.default.Loader
settings -> transport:amqp results:disabled
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Experiencing same problem with --detach or multi

Comment: worker will respond to "inspect" commands, which means its connected to the same backend, so it does get hold of the correct configuration...

Comment: Tried installing the app package globally, but still same behaviour. out of ideas now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug with 4.4.7. Downgrading to 4.4.6 or upgrading to 5 should fix it.

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6370

Comment: Thanks @Giannis, that makes sense. 
Did that work for you?

Comment: I have upgraded to 5.0.2, but tested with 4.4.6 and it works as well.

Comment: I'm Sorry for the delayed(very) response. Been away from this project for a while. Still not able to update at the moment due to conflicts with django-celery-results and flower. I may have to drop flower...