# Celery worker - detach mode doesn't load app correctly

Tags: python, celery

My original problem is that when running celery worker with --detach flag, or using celery multi, my application tasks are not registered with the workers ( although the workers do startup and are reachable, same is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64531521/celery-worker-only-imports-tasks-when-not-detached) ). To help debug this problem I have made a plain celery app, which has a different but maybe related issue.

Source structure

```
setup.py
example
    | tasks.py
    | celery.py
    | __init__.py
    | __main__.py
```

tasks.py:

```
from example.celery import app

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

celery.py

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379', include=["example.tasks"])
```

**init**.py

```
__version__ = "0.0.1"
__package__ = "example"

from example.celery import app
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
import example

setup(
    name=example.__package__,
    version=example.__version__,
    include_package_data=True,
    python_requires=">=3.7",
)
```

Install the package using
`$ pip install -e .`

From anywhere in the system I can now run
`$ celery -A example worker`

And I will have a worker with the add task. Adding --detach flag like this:
`$ celery -A example.celery.app worker --detach --logfile=$HOME/celery.log`

Will give an error trying to connect to AMQPLAIN into the celery.log file, when the app is configured to use Redis:

```
...
amqp.exceptions.AccessRefused: (0, 0): (403) ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
```

So my understanding is that something is going off when the worker tries to load the celery app in detach mode, but I can't figure out what. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Using celery==4.4.7

**Update**
This works with celery 5.0.2, will be opening a bug ticket.

Comment: Erm... `celery -A example worker` is different from `celery -A example.celery.app worker`, right?

Comment: I don't think so, my understanding is that celery will search for an app inside 'example', by passing the full path there is just less to search for. I have tried both approaches

Comment: In that case, the reason why it was failing is most likely PYTHONPATH ... Export PYTHONPATH=<directory containing example> and run the thing again.

Comment: "example" is installed globally. This is working with latest celery, so it may be a bug

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug which I missed.
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6370